# Is object initializer avalible in flutter (dart) like java or c# in the spirit of the following code?

Tags: java, c#, flutter, dart

Is object initializer avalible in flutter  (dart) like java or c# in the spirit of the following code?

```
Person p = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address = new Address()
    {
        Street = "1234 St.",
        City = "Phoenix"
    }
};
```

Comment: No. This is a wrong syntax for dart.

Comment: Anonymous classes are not available in dart

Comment: This isn't an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same effect in Dart, use named parameters in the constructor. For example:

```
class Person {
  Person({ this.firstName, this.lastName, this.address, this.tn });

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String tn;
  Address address;
}

class Address {
  Address({ this.street, this.city, this.zip });
 
  String street;
  String city;
  String zip;
}
```

Now you could initialize some or all of the fields in these classes by using the named parameters - just providing only the argument and values you need, and in any order. For example:

```
// create a person with no fields initialized
var person = Person(); 

// only init first and last
var person1 = Person(firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'); 

// this is equivalent to the OPs question
var person2 = Person(address: Address(street: '1234 St.', city: 'Phoenix'), 
  lastName: 'Doe', firstName: 'John');
```